# How to check 8266 module

Tags: esp8266

I am using an Arduino board with an ESP8266 module to connect to a WiFi device.
How do I check if the device is connected?

Comment: Which Arduino board? Check the associated stations on your router to see if the device is associated (connected) to your router

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
AT+ CWJAP?
```

or

```
AT+ CIPSTATUS
```

to see if you're connected to wifi. (The first will tell you access point status, the second will tell you IP address.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18983)

Comment: Revised to be the form of an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,If your ESP8266 module is coded then AT commands won't be responding directly, In that case You can check in Serial monitor(if u already wrote print in the existing code on module) else u have to flash a new code.

If didn't flash any code then use AT commands(AT+CWJAP?) for checking SSID.
(AT+ CIPSTATUS) for IP adress.